# Could not load type 'Context' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: .net-core, upgrade, preview

Where using .netcore **2.2** an upgrade to .netcore **3.0**

This is the error that we encounter when running unit test:

> "Could not load type 'Context' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=3.0.0.0"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These steps work on our project:

1. Remove old packages

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.2.0" />
```

2. Install

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing 3.0.0-preview7.19365.7
```

3. Update Startup.cs

```
    .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.Load("YourProjectControllerNamespace"))
```

Comment: I have the same problem.
Could you share this AddAppilcationPart in more detail, I'm not sure what assembly to load.

Comment: Had the same issue and for me it was enough to do step 1 and 2 to make it work again (but since 3.0 is GA I didn't have to use a preview version).